# Looking for substring alternative javascript

Tags: javascript, methods, substring, angularjs-ng-href

Basically my problem is I am using the substring method on the variable version for the result then to be used inside a URL using ng-href:

```
substring(0, 3)
version 9.1.0 = 9.1 (good)
version 9.2.0 = 9.2 (good)
version 9.3.0 = 9.3 (good)
..
version 9.10.0 = 9.1 (breaks here)
version 10.1.0 = 10. (breaks here)
```

As you can see eventually the substring method stops working, how can I fix this??

Comment: use `substring(0,version.length-2)`. This way you'll always trim the last 2 symbols from your version.

Comment: You should use a `Regex`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the substring the other way by removing the last two character which will be a dot and a numeric character:

```js
function version(val){
  console.log(val.substring(0,val.length-2))
} 
version('9.1.0');
version('9.2.0');
version('9.3.0');
version('9.10.0');
version('10.1.0');
```

But what if there are two numeric character and a dot at the end? Here is that solution:

```js
function version(val){
  var tempVersion = val.split('.');
  tempVersion.pop();
  console.log(tempVersion.join('.'))
} 
version('9.1.0');
version('9.2.0');
version('9.3.1020');
version('9.10.0');
version('10.1.0123');
```

Answer (score 17):

the equivalent is `substring()`
check the MDN [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)

Answer (score 2):

Use `split` and `join` on the dot, and during the time you manipulate an array, use `slice` to remove the last item:

```js
const inputs = ['9.1.0', '9.2.0', '9.3.0', '9.10.0', '10.1.0', '22.121.130'];

inputs.forEach(input => {
  const result = input.split('.').slice(0, -1).join('.');
  console.log(input, '=>', result);
})
```

Simple enough and it will work whatever your version number :)

Hoping that will help you!

Answer (score 1):

`/^\d+\.\d+/` will match the first 2 digits with dot between.

The `regex` will not have to process the entire input like the `split` approaches do.

It will also catch consecutive `.` like `30..40`.  And spaces.

It will even catch alphabetic parts like `10.B`

This also will extend if you want to start allowing segments such as `-alpha`, `-beta`, etc.

```js
const rx = /^\d+\.\d+/

const inputs = ['9.1.0', '9.2.0', '9.3.0', '9.10.0', 
'10.1.0', , '22.121.130', '10.A', '10..20', '10. 11', '10 .11'];

inputs.forEach(input => {
  const m = rx.exec(input)
  console.log(input, m ? m[0] : 'not found')
})
```